# Is there an entangled ground state solution to the hydrogen atom? (spin neglected)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-entanglement, hydrogen

When solving the hydrogen atom, to separate the two-particle Time-Independent Schrödinger Equation (TISE) into two separate equations, we make the change of variables:

$$\vec{r}_{CM} = \frac{m_e}{m_e+m_p}\vec{r}_e + \frac{m_p}{m_e+m_p}\vec{r}_p$$
$$\vec{r}_{rel} = \vec{r}_e - \vec{r}_p$$

Where the subscripts $e$ and $p$ are for the electron and proton, and $CM$ and $rel$ are notation for the center-of-mass and relative coordinates.

We then look for solutions of the form
$$\psi(\vec{r}_{CM}, \vec{r}_{rel}) = \psi_1(\vec{r}_{CM})\psi_2(\vec{r}_{rel})$$

namely a product (non-entangled) state. This is successful and it splits the TISE into two separate equations. However in the sources I have used, it was not proven that the only solutions to the two-body TISE are of this form. Are there other solutions? In other words, is it possible that a state which entangles the two coordinates could also solve the two-body TISE?

I am looking at the problem neglecting spin at the moment.